# Can you help me understand the missing steps in solving this inequality for n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[Updated]

I’m working on exercise 1-2.2 from [Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition):

> Suppose we are comparing implementations of insertion sort and merge sort on the same machine. For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in $8n^2$ steps, while merge sort runs in 64n lg n steps. For which values of n does insertion sort beat merge sort?

I am having a hard time following the solution given [here](https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap01/1.2/).

$$
\begin{align}
8 n^2 &< 64\,n\,log_2{n} \tag{1}\\
2^n &< n^8 \tag{2} \\
n &\le 43 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

I don’t understand how line 1 leads to line 2, and line 2 to line 3.

On my own I got from line 1 to $n \lt 8\,log_2n$ but I don’t see where to go from there.

Comment: It would be better if you actually type your question -- including the inequalities that you're asking about -- in here, rather than inserting an image.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When you edit your post to add the question, please also add your attempts at solving the problem, and in the process use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to make the equations look good.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n> 0$ we can devide both sides by $8n$ so it becomes:

$$n<8\lg(n)$$

Since $\lg(n)=\log_2(n)$ (I prefer this notation):

$$n<8\log_2(n)$$

Now we use a property of logarithms:

$$b\log(a)=\log(a^b)$$

So:

$$n<\log_2(n^8)$$

Applying the exponential in base $2$ to both terms:

$$2^n<n^8$$

:)

Comment: Is guess-and-check the best method for getting from your last line to n <= 43?

Comment: @NathanRosquist There are some methods called of approximation, but they are pretty advanced for your level. Guess and check is the best but don't do it ingenously. First of all notice that $2^{10}\approx 1000=10^3$ so if $n=40$ then $2^{40}<40^8 \Rightarrow  2^{40}<2^{16} 10^8 \Rightarrow 2^{24}<10^8 \Rightarrow (2^{10})^2 2^4<10^8  \Rightarrow (2^{10})^2 2^4 \approx (10^3)^2 16 <10^8 \Rightarrow  16<100$ So the condition is still satisfied for $n=40$ but for a a little considering that the growth of the first term is exponential. So you should try values a little bigger than $n=40$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
8n^2 &< 64 n \lg n
\\
n & < 8 \lg n & \text{divide both sides by $8n$}
\\
2^n &< 2^{8 \lg n} = n^8 &\text{exponentiate both sides}.
\end{align}
The last line $n \le 43$ comes from some guess-and-check.

Comment: You should justify why you can divide by $n$, this is not always possible in disequations.